# plt.savefig saves a blank plot when using function to execute

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a save button that when clicked will save the plot. When I use the command plt.savefig("SiLorentzFit2.png"), it saves just fine and I can see the plot as a .png. When I try to use a function to execute the same command, the plot saves a blank .png and gives back <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> after pressing the button. How do I get the plot to save normally using the button code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

   
def lorentz(x, y0, amp, cen, wid):
    return y0 + (2*amp/np.pi)*(wid/(4*(x-cen)**2 + wid**2))

  
xtest = np.linspace(400,650,250)
y0 = 1000
amp = 10000
cen = 511
wid = 2

ytest = lorentz(xtest,y0,amp,cen, wid)
plt.plot(xtest,ytest)
plt.title("Fitting function")
plt.ylabel("Intenisty")
plt.xlabel("Raman shift (cm$^{-1}$)")

def save_plot(b):
    plt.savefig("SiLorentzFit2.png")
    print("File Saved!")
    

saveplot = Button(description="Save Plot")
saveplot.on_click(save_plot)
display(saveplot)
```

Comment: Why does function `save_plot()` have a variable `b` when `b` is not used in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

   
def lorentz(x, y0, amp, cen, wid):
    return y0 + (2*amp/np.pi)*(wid/(4*(x-cen)**2 + wid**2))

  
xtest = np.linspace(400,650,250)
y0 = 1000
amp = 10000
cen = 511
wid = 2

ytest = lorentz(xtest,y0,amp,cen, wid)


def save_plot(b):
    plt.plot(xtest,ytest)
    plt.title("Fitting function")
    plt.ylabel("Intenisty")
    plt.xlabel("Raman shift (cm$^{-1}$)")
    plt.savefig(b)
    print("File Saved!")
    
save_plot("SiLorentzFit2.png")
```